# What other prime numbers have been ruled out as counterexamples to the Feit-Thompson conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Given distinct primes $p$ and $q$, $$\frac{p^{\,q} - 1}{p - 1}$$ is never a divisor of $$\frac{q^{\,p} - 1}{q - 1}.$$ Or so we believe. If $p = 2$, then it's clear that no odd prime $q$ can make a counterexample. If $p = 3$, then we have $$\frac{3^q - 1}{2}$$ and $$\frac{q^3 - 1}{q - 1}.$$ I am confident that with time I can prove there's no counterexample here either, but it's of course quite laborious to go through the primes one by one. Has anyone been able to rule out a bunch of primes at once?

Comment: It appears that for odd $a$ we have $\dfrac{(6x+1)^a-1}{6x}\equiv a\bmod6$ and $\dfrac{(6x-1)^a-1}{6x-2}\equiv 1\bmod6$, which would imply for instance that $p\equiv q\bmod6$ for $p,q>3$.

Comment: By elementary means  if $ p=3<q$ is a counterexample then $ r=q^2+q+1$ is also prime  and  $3^q-1$ is divisible by $ r$.

Comment: *a)* Hmm, in wikipedia they focus ***divisibility*** of one cyclotomic expression by the other one (and no counterexample is known) and in Weissstein's mathworld they focus on ***common factors*** (gcd()) and document one known case as counterexample. Which is the original Feit-Thompson-conjecture? *b)* How should ever $(q^3-1)/(q-1)$ be divisible by $(3^q-1)/(3-1)$ when $q$ is larger than $3$? Didn't you confuse the direction of divisibility here?

Comment: Ah, I found in the wp-linked article *Feit, Walter, and John G. Thompson. “A Solvability Criterion for Finite Groups and Some Consequences.”* that $p \gt q$ was assumed and ***divisibility*** was focused.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $(3^q-1)(q-1)>2(q^3-1)$ for every $q>3$. This is because $3$ is the point where the two lines meet, and $3^q$ grows faster than $q^3$.

Now, we simply let $q$ and $n$ be prime and natural (respectively) such that $n(\frac{3^q-1}{2})=\frac{q^3-1}{q-1}$.

Then, $n(3^q-1)=2(\frac{q^3-1}{q-1})$, and thus $n(3^q-1)(q-1)=2(q^3-1)$.
This means that $q\leq3$. Of course, because the final equation also holds for both $2$ and $3$, this means that there are no numbers greater than 3 where this is true. So, there are no counterexamples.